# ionic lazy loading. Importing services into lazy-loaded pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-services

So I have 2 pages that are lazy loaded which means they both have their own module file.

`NewsFeed.component.ts` declared in `NewsFeed.module.ts`

and

`NewsFeedItem.componenet.ts` declared in `NewsFeedItem.module.ts`

(clicking on an item in newsFeed navigates you to newsFeedItem)

however they get data their from a service

```
NewsFeed.service.ts
```

This service has 2 get requests, one for retrieving all items, used in `NewsFeed.component.ts`
and one for retrieving a single item used in `NewsFeedItem.component.ts`
(using an `id` passed in during navigation)

Currently I have imported this service into both modules which apparently is a big no as that creates 2 copies of it.

My question is what is the best practice here? Do I separate the 2 functions into their own services? Or do I declare the service in a core module which I have and use for basic services that are used throughout the app

Comment: You should import your service in `app.module.ts` to use throughout the app

Answer (score -1):

You should create two separate function in service file. One for getting all the record and one for getting id based record.

Comment: thats how it currently is. 2 get request functions. I'm wondering if I should split the service into 2 services with one function per service. or keep it as is but move it into the coreModule

Comment: You can move it to coreModule so that it can be easily available to all modules. But one service per function is not good approach to follow.